# Shimano SM RT800 rotors on BR-RX400 brakes

Tags: shimano, disc-brake, compatibility

I just want to make sure that I can put the Ultegra ice-tech 160mm rotors on my gravel bike that currently has BR-RX400 brakes and SM-RT70 CL rotors.

On Shimano website https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc/rx400/2x10 it says that SM-RT64
is recommended, but that's not the one I currently have stock (mixed drivetrain from Scott). I assume that it will work great with Ultegra rotors? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there aren't really any caveats with mixing and matching rotors within Shimano's line, assuming the correct size, mounting type, and pad compound (in the case of the low-end Resin Only rotors).